# Heroku local web application is not recognizing Procfile PHP

Tags: php, heroku

I've been trying to connect my local files to my app using `heroku local web`, but it throws this error:

```
3:24:15 AM web.1 |  'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
3:24:15 AM web.1 |  operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
3:24:15 AM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

I'm sure my Procfile is there in the directory and here is the command line `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`.
What I'm doing wrong? What is `vendor` and why it's not recognizing it?

Additional info:

- OS: Windows 10
- buildpack: PHP

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks like you're running this in `cmd.exe`. Commands there often use forward slashes for options (e.g. `foo /a /b`) instead of dashes (e.g. `foo -a -b`).

I believe the slashes in your command are being interpreted as options, making `vendor` the command that would run.

A common pattern for using a different command local development on Windows is to create a file called `Procfile.windows` containing a Windows-specific command, e.g. one that uses backslashes instead of forward slashes, and then run locally as `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`.

But that `heroku-php-apache2` binary is unlikely to run on Windows, so that will be insufficient. The [getting started with PHP](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php) page is notably missing the "run the app locally" step that, for example, [the Python page has](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally).

One good option is to use [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) to run a Linux distribution in Windows and develop there. Another might be to use something like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) or [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to run a development environment in a virtual machine.

Or, if you have PHP installed on Windows already, try using something like [`php -S`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) instead of Apache:

```
web: php -S localhost:8000 -t main_folder/
```

Make sure to keep your existing `Procfile` as you'll want to use that on Heroku. `php -S` should only be used for local development.

You might also simply have better luck using PowerShell instead of cmd.exe. It is generally much better-behaved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Chris. I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong because it throws this error now `Error in argument 1, char 2: no argument for usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]`

Comment: @LiquiKal, I made several different suggestions. Can you be more specific?

Comment: My bad, the change I did was in the `Procfile`, I typed in `web: php -S` and now whenever I run the code that error shows up.

Comment: @LiquiKal, it's been a while since I actually used PHP and I forgot an argument. You'll need to provide an IP address or host name and port to run on as well. And, optionally, you can use `-t` to point the server to whatever folder it should serve. I've updated my answer accordingly.